# “Last update failed” - Windows IoT Update error

Tags: windows-iot

Just installed Windows IoT on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ and whenever I try to check for updates from the Windows Device Portal, I get the following error:
"Last update failed". Everything else is going fine.

Any ideas how to solve this? Or at least to identify the error by any internal logging anywhere (which I couldn't find).